# Is the concept of pressure applicable to liquids & gasses only or solids as well?

Tags: pressure, mass

I have notice that `pressure` is spoken of only for liquids and gases but not solids. Am I correct that the equivalent for solids is `centre of mass` ?

Is `pressure` valid for solids as well?

Imagine a pane of glass laid horizontally. If I want to put a heavy thing on it (say a cement block) then the glass might not break if the weight of the cement block is distributed (thin, flat block) but could break if the weight is not distributed (small size but same weight as the thin one). Does this mean that the thin slab exerts less pressure than the small solid one? What is the role of `centre of mass` here?

Comment: "equivalent for solids is centre of mass" is wrong. pressure is force over area, the center of mass is a geometrical point see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers tell you, pressure is a relevant quantity for solids.

However, while pressure is the only kind of "force per area" (technically a stress) a liquid or gas can hold at rest, for a solid you have to invoke the full stress tensor $\mathbf{\sigma}$, as those can transmit shear forces.

The stress tensor can be understood by cutting a small piece out of the solid. It describes which force must act on each of the wall pieces to keep the solid in place: The force per unit area for a wall whose normal is $\vec n$ is given by $$\vec f = \mathbf{\sigma} \vec n$$.

For a liquid or gas at rest $\mathrm{\sigma}$ will take the form
$$ \mathbf{\sigma} = \begin{pmatrix} p & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & p & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & p\end{pmatrix}. $$

That is, no matter how you orient the faces of your little cut out piece, the force to keep things in place will always be parallel to the normal, and the same in all directions (those are exactly the basic properties of pressure taught in elementary science classe).

For a solid the other components may be non-zero, and the diagonal stresses in the different axes may differ. Therefore the pressure doesn't provide the whole picture.

We can, however, always decompose the stresses into a pressure part, and the trace free shear stresses, as follows:

$$ \mathbf{\sigma} = \frac 1 3 \text{tr}(\sigma) \mathbf{1} + \tilde \sigma $$

And then we can identify the pressure in a solid as
$$ p = \frac 1 3 \text{tr}(\sigma). $$

(Note, that compressibility $\kappa$ in the sense $\Delta V = \kappa p$ does not work for solids if the shear forces are non-zero).

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is nothing more than a surface force, with one subtlety: it has no direction. Given pressure $P$ at a point and a small surface $d\vec{S}$, the force exerted on the surface is:
$$d\vec{F}=P\,d\vec{S}$$
This definition doesn't require the system to be a liquid or a gas.

Leaving mechanics for thermodynamics, the definition of pressure (for example the derivative of internal energy with volume) is also universal for all systems.

In fact, whole parts of thermodynamics study the role of pressure with solid objects. Think about this well-known phase diagram for a pure system:

[image: phase diagram]

You have to specify both pressure and temperature to know in which state a pure system is at equilibrium. Notice however that the solid-liquid curve is almost vertical, meaning that pressure has little effect on those phases. This explains that pressure isn't always mentioned for a solid or liquid system.

The center of mass doesn't play any role in writing the pressure force, but it can of course be useful to compute the motion of the system due to this pressure force with Newton's second law.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of pressure is certainly present in solids; there is some measure of compressibility in all materials, and while solids are only slightly susceptible to compression, sound in solids travels both as transverse
waves, and as longitudinal waves.    Longitudinal waves
are compression waves, like a sound wave in air, while
transverse waves,such as a plucked string, are also seen in
solids but not in air or other fluids.

The bulk modulus measures compressibility; for steel,
bulk modulus is $$1.6 x 10^{11} pascals$$, and is
defined as the ratio of pressure to fractional volume
change.

Pressure, though, is not the whole of the stress picture in solids; if it were, those transverse waves wouldn't
exist.